# how to limit on woocommerce product buying

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an educational and course sales website. I want to limit my products so that every user can buy each product once.
When the course is purchased, the Add to Cart button will be disabled and the text of the button change to you are now member of course.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'woo_custom_add_to_cart' );
 
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity','prevent_repaet_buy');
function prevent_repaet_buy(){
  $user=get_current_user_id();
  global $product;
  $id = $product->get_id();
  $downloads     = WC()->customer->get_meta();
  echo "<pre>";
    print_r($downloads);
      echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: The code you added to your question really **doesn't make any sense**. That is why I see your question as a 'write code for me request'. **Pure code-writing requests and/or recommendations are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow**, we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: If I knew, I would write the code myself, there was no need to ask here.

Comment: There is a difference between **getting stuck on something while trying** and **i have no idea, can someone do this for me**. As I mentioned earlier, stackoverflow is not the right place for those kinds of requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function disable_repeat_purchase( $purchasable, $product ) {
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        return $purchasable;
    }

    // Get the ID for the current product
    $product_id = $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ? $product->variation_id : $product->id; 

    // return false statement if the customer has bought the product / variation
    if ( wc_customer_bought_product( wp_get_current_user()->user_email, get_current_user_id(), $product_id ) ) {
        $purchasable = false;
        echo '<p class="btn btn-info">you are now member of course </p>';
    }

    // Double-check for variations: if parent is not purchasable, then variation is not
    if ( $purchasable && $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ) {
        $purchasable = $product->parent->is_purchasable();
    }

    return $purchasable;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'disable_repeat_purchase', 10, 2 );
```